# How to type component using React Native Navigation and Typescript with registerComponent

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a component registered like so:

```
  Navigation.registerComponent(screens.myScreen, () => props => (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MyScreen {...props} />
    </Provider>
  ));
```

I have an interface for this component it where I can type props:

```
export interface MyScreen extends [WIX NATIVE NAVIGATION INTERFACE] {
...
...
}
```

I would like to extend this interface to include the props from React Native Navigation `registerComponent` but I haven't found the right declaration yet to replace `[WIX NATIVE NAVIGATION INTERFACE]`.

Does `Wix react native navigation` provides an interface for it?